# How to get value of nested Map using parameter

Tags: sql, json, apache-camel

I'm trying to get value of nested Map using parameter of SQL component expression but it failed.

I have this json (unmarshal to java.util.Map):

```
{ "username" : "john",
  "company" : { "companycode" : "stackoverflow.inc",
                "address" : "Street 12" }
}
```

And I have this SQL expression with parameters on my Route builder:

```
...
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
.to("sql:INSERT INTO user_tab VALUES (:#username, :#company.companycode)")
...
```

I was able to get the value of **username** but I can not get the value of **companycode**. What is the right way to do it? Thank you.

Comment: Try with #company['companyCode'] to make it a map lookup with that key

Comment: @ClausIbsen Thank you for your answer, but it's not working. Camel said that company is not an Array.

Answer (score 0):

according: http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html

> From Camel 2.14 onward you can use Simple expressions as parameters as shown:

`sql:select * from table where id=:#${property.myId} order by name[?options]`

this work fine for me:

`{guid=67, properties={last_seen=1472034553348, _type=business_service, name=Anna, created_at=1472033602648, status=USUNIĘTY}}`

`<to uri="dbSQL:insert into table_name (
  guid,name,description,type,status,changedate,transid,transseq
) values (
  :#${body[guid]}::integer, :#${body[properties][name]}, :#${body[properties][name]}, :#${body[properties][_type]}, :#${body[properties][staus]}, now(), 0, 0
)"/>`